# app:shrinkReleaseMultiDexComponents Error

Tags: android, gradle

When i create an Signed APK it gives an error:

`Error:Execution failed for task :app:shrinkReleaseMultiDexComponents`.

> java.io.IOException: The output jar [G:\D drive\CommunityMatrimony\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\release\componentClasses.jar] must be specified after an input jar, or it will be empty.

This is my Gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'xxxx'
            keyPassword 'xxxx'
            storeFile file('F:/CMJAR.jks')
            storePassword 'xxxx'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx.yyyy"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 42
        versionName "2.8.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/godel-release/godel/"
    }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencies {
    provided fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/AF-Android-SDK-v2.3.1.18.jar')
    compile(name: 'gamooga-livechat-client-release', ext: 'aar')
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.6'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.1'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.async:androidasync:2.1.6'
    compile 'in.juspay:godel:0.6.6'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```